# JTabbedPane without Tab header

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Hi guys i writing an app that have JTabbedPane in it. but the problem is it's always have tab header on it.

[image]

i want to remove that tab header and make JTabbedPane look like an rectangle one.

Here my code:

```
public final static JTabbedPane getTabbedPane()
{
   JTabbedPane jtp=new JTabbedPane();

   jtp.add(new JLabel("Tab"));
   jtp.add(new JLabel("Tab"));
   jtp.add(new JLabel("Tab"));
   jtp.add(new JLabel("Tab"));


   return jtp;
}
```

Comment: i don't get what you want .. you want like a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout` ?

Comment: What i want is remove that Tab's Header and make it like normal rectangle.

Comment: yeah you write the same in question, i still don't understand.. i think you want a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout`

Comment: It would seem a `JTabbedPane` without the tabs ..isn't a `JTabbedPane`!  How is the user supposed to change between them?  I agree with @nachokk and @mKorbel it really sounds as though you want a `CardLayout`..

Comment: Maybe i should you other component like JLabel to make it like that. Thz for your answer. and @Andrew i can write code to make it change between that tab. just use:
    JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(int index)

Comment: well with a `CardLayout` you have an easy way too [How To Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want to remove that tab header and make JTabbedPane look like an
>   rectangle one.

- no idea whats your goal
- use `CardLayout`
- set `LineBorder` for `JLabel`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Here is an clean example, it works for me :
[image]

[image]

```
JPanel panelOutils =  new JPanel();
panelOutils.add(ongletOutils); 
JScrollPane scrollOutils = new JScrollPane(panelOutils,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); 
JTabbedPane jTabbedPaneOutils = new JTabbedPane();
// With Tab header 
jTabbedPaneOutils.add(scrollOutils);        
this.addTab("Outils", jTabbedPaneOutils);

// Delete tab header  
this.addTab("Outils", jTabbedPaneOutils.add(scrollOutils));
```